# Disable email management in django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using `django-allauth` and wondering what The Right Way™️ to disable email management is. Some context: accounts are created on behalf of users, and they should stick to their (institutional) email address.

Should I just override the templates and remove `accounts/email` from `allauth.urls` or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From allauth:

> ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION (="mandatory" | "optional" | "none")
>     Determines the e-mail verification method during signup. When set to
>     "mandatory" the user is blocked from logging in until the email
>     address is verified. Choose "optional" or "none" to allow logins
>     with an unverified e-mail address. In case of "optional", the e-mail
>     verification mail is still sent, whereas in case of "none" no e-mail
>     verification mails are sent.

You probably want to set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION  = "none"` in your `settings.py`. If you want to completely disable the function for users to add multiple email addresses you'd  probably need to override `accounts/email` template and you can also override the url in your `urls.py` to use a different view.

Comment: That's a good point on `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION`. I ended up defining `accounts/email` before including `allauth.urls`: `path("accounts/email/", default_views.page_not_found, kwargs={"exception": Exception("Page not Found")},)`